# When i am changing the value of one variable another is also changing

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am gettting value from the database by using following method and inserting the output data into two variables and when i am changing the values in $scope.contactRole then the value of 'contactRoleForTrace' is also changing but i don't want to change it.So can you please tell me how can i do it?

```
var contactRoleForTrace = [];
$scope.getUserRoles = (function () {
    //Method to get data from database
    intakeAppFactory.getRoles(item)
        .success(function (data) {
            contactRoleForTrace = data;
            $scope.contactRole = data;
        }).error(function (data, status) {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occured!";
        });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently you are directly assigning `data` object reference to `contactRoleForTrace` & `$scope.contactRole`, so any changes happen to `$scope.contactRole`/`data` will automatically update `contactRoleForTrace` variable as they are bounded to same reference(`data` object).

You should use `angular.copy` which will create clone of the `data` object and so the `contactRoleForTrace` & `$scope.contactRole` will point to different reference.

```
contactRoleForTrace = angular.copy(data);
```

Comment: I agree with your answer, but maybe it is worth to mention that if you are using 2 arrays with the same data on the code probably (not sure) you should rethink this object's. Note: if the main reason to this is track the differences probably there are other ways to track the old values and the new values.

Comment: @JoseRocha well, I see your point.. but what I assumed is, OP wanted to implement functionality of `Revert Changes` where he might providing option to to form level changes back to original(before editing form) by clicking on same button.. you meant to say OP should go for watch to compare old & new values to get difference?

Comment: I hope that you don't get me wrong your answer is the right answer to the question. I was only saying it could be improved as an "extra mile". Ng-watch is a good example to keep track on the changes (as long as you don-t ng-watch every thing). Other thing is if the op wants to completely revert (for example a form) the data that is possible to edit should be load again and not reverted with data previously load (from my experience this could prevent some future problems).

Comment: @JoseRocha Thanks, I'm not kind of agree with what you are saying.  From my experience, I personally prefer to avoid watcher as it bad practice to use it.. and your second point like you are suggesting to reload page, I'd just prefer to keep copy of old object when user landed on page, and will reassign object when user say "Revert Changes"(there is not much advantage of this over what you are suggesting, but I feel this as conformable & I'm also reducing one server round triop)

Comment: Ok I understand and respect the decision.

Comment: @JoseRocha Let me clear why I don't prefer to reload page,.Suppose take an example of page, which consist of many sections & the form which user is editing is one of the section of it, so when you try to reload that page(mean state/route refresh of router) can lead to ask for whole bunch of data for a page again(other sections ajax will be going to happen for no reason), then rather reloading page I'd specifically ask for data of form instead of reloading whole page route. Thanks :)

Comment: Just to clear from my side, I was not talking about reloading the full page but to reload data (or partial data) on the page. I'm agaisnt reload a page without explicit need for it.